# apache ReverseProxy configuration (apache web server url is changed to jboss server's url)

Tags: java, apache, jboss, webserver, appserver

I have configured apache web server with jboss and integrated using mod_jk, now the problem is when i hit the url of webserver  http://webserv.my.project.com:8080/index.html, after login to the application the url is automatically changed to appserver that is http://appserv.my.project.com:8080/login.jsp,
problem: url is changed to application server
expected: url should be same as webserver throughout the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the problem, I need to configure ReverseProxy at apache web server side. i followed below links to resolve the issue

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies